# Add local files to haskell libraries search path

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am running `Examples/Producer.hs` from the [hafka](https://github.com/tcrayford/hafka) project. It throws error as,

```
Could not find module ‘Network.Kafka.Producer’
```

Library file `Network.Kafka.Producer` is sitting in my local repository and not inside default library paths (`/home/user/.cabal`). How can i add this local file system path to the Cabal/Haskell library?

In python terms, this question is equivalent to appending an entry to `PYTHONPATH` list as,

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/local/fs
```

Comment: I guess you cloned the git right? In this case I would use a sandbox and `cabal install` there - after this you should be fine using `cabal repl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include it as is by using `-i` when compiling with ghc.

Fore example, `ghc ...... -i/path/to/local/fs`